# c# populate listview from dictionary with multiple values

Tags: c#, listview, dictionary

I have a Dictionary with multiple values that I want to use to populate a listview.

I get an "ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled" and "invalidArgument=Value of '1' is not valid for 'index'.

here is what I hope is enough of the revelant code:

```
public partial class frmResultList : Form
{

    public class MyLookupCustList
    {
        public string sEstNum { get; set; }
        public string sLName  { get; set; }
        public string sFName  { get; set; }
        public string sCity   { get; set; }
    }

    public frmResultList(int iMyCount, Dictionary<string, frmResultList.MyLookupCustList> MyDictList)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        fillListView(iMyCount, MyDictList);
    }

    public void fillListView(int iMyCount, Dictionary<string, frmResultList.MyLookupCustList> MyDictList)
    {

        listView1.Clear();

        ListViewItem item;

        for (int i = 0; i < iMyCount; i++)
        {
            listView1.Items.Clear();
            var o = MyDictList[i.ToString()];
            var myListViewItem = new ListViewItem();

            myListViewItem = this.listView1.Items.Add(i.ToString());
            myListViewItem.SubItems[1].Text = o.sEstNum;
            myListViewItem.SubItems[2].Text = o.sLName;
            myListViewItem.SubItems[3].Text = o.sFName;
            myListViewItem.SubItems[4].Text = o.sCity;

            listView1.Items.Add(myListViewItem);

        }

        listView1.View = View.Details;         
        listView1.Show();
        listView1.Refresh();


    }
```

I get the exception when I try to insert the first SubItem 
Here ===> myListViewItem.SubItems[1].Text = o.sEstNum;
please help, what do I need to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to update item with index [1], that item doesn't exist yet, you need to create it first. Same will happen for your sub items that you are trying to access - 2, 3, 4
So you need to have logic to check whether the item exists first, if it does update it, otherwise add it.

Comment: When I look at o.sEstNum it has "648".

Comment: right, o.sEstNum is not the issue, its the other side of the equation. when debugging, look at your `myListViewItem.SubItems`, I bet it is null. If that's the case, you need to create items inside the subitems list before trying to access it. I am trying to get a sample for you, but I don't see `SubItems` property on the `ListViewItem`.